# Has there been experimental evidence that entangled state collapses simultaneously?

Tags: quantum-entanglement, measurement-problem, wavefunction-collapse, bells-inequality, non-locality

If we observe the observable of one particle among two particles which are entangled each other and separated far away, we can determine the value of the other particle’s same observable from the result of measurement, even though they are separated far away. However, we also accept that the observation to one particle collapses two particles’ entangled state simultaneously into eigenstate of observable and I understand that this is why quantum mechanics is non-local theory. The hypothesis that observable of two particles is already determined by local hidden variable was denied by the violation of Bell’s inequality.
**My question is, has there been experimental evidence that entangled state collapses simultaneously?** This seems like to be accepted without any doubt in explaining entanglement and non-locality of quantum mechanics, but in my opinion, this is the key aspect that makes quantum mechanics to non-local theory and I could not find the convincing evidence or proof that confirm that entangled state collapses simultaneously.

Comment: "Simultaneously" is a loaded term for separated particles. "Collapse" is a loaded term for quantum systems. So there's a lot that goes into answering this question! If we treat violations of Bell's inequality as explaining something about separated particles, I think that answers whether two effects are happening "simultaneously" - at least there are some nonlocal correlations. In terms of "collapse" - if we understand this term as a way of interpretting the results of quantum experiments, then again Bell-type experiments are the answer. Nobody ever shows that collapse actually happens.

Comment: I appreciate your kindness to explain what is the actual point of problem. I think that I misunderstood about the collapse of state. With some thought experiment based on your explanation, I think that I found the answer to my own doubt. Thank you!!